# Error with data return by the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm developing an app with C# in MVC. This app consumes a WCF for the data. The WCF is fine because when I execute the WCF Test Client the data return for the service are right but when I try to access through the view, the page display the message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AlergomuciaMVC.ServiceReference1.Section[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'AlergomuciaMVC.ServiceReference1.Section'.

This is my code:
In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    ServiceReference1.ServiceClient sec = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
    return View(sec.GetSectionById(id));
}
```

In the view I use this model: `@model AlergomuciaMVC.ServiceReference1.Section`

And this is the code in the service:

```
public List<Section> GetSectionById(int id)
{
    List<Section> Sec = new List<Section>();
    DbDataReader dr = Consult.returnData("Select  id, seccion from seccionespdf where id = " + id);

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Section s = new Section();

        s.id = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
        s.seccion = dr[1].ToString();

        Sec.Add(s);
    }
    return Sec;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: you are returning multiple sections while view expects single object on Section

Comment: In other words, change your service to return a Section not List of Section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only return a single object from your service as you are fetching data on basis of id.

```
public Section GetSectionById(int id)
{

    DbDataReader dr = Consult.returnData("Select  id, seccion from seccionespdf where id = " + id);
    Section Sec = new Section();    
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Sec.id = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
        Sec.seccion = dr[1].ToString();


    }
    return Sec;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mairaj, Ehsan and Crowcoder. It's working fine.